# How do I store lookup tables in magic numbers?

Tags: python, dictionary, lookup-tables, magic-numbers

I have seen something interesting [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python/41742#41742), saying you can store lookup tables at magic numbers.

I have tried using brute-force to find the magic number, but all the results are incorrect.

How do I find the correct magic number for a certain lookup table?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the author of that answer puts it:

> The magic number stores the table as a bitstring, with the `n`-th
>   digit (from the end) corresponding to the `n`th table entry

Here's a really simple example:

```
Entry   Value   Bit
-----   -----   ---
  0     True     1
  1     False    0
  2     False    0
  3     True     1
                 b  # needed to indicate
                 0  # 'binary number'
```

So the *"magic number"* for this lookup table, reading **up from the bottom**, is:

```
>>> 0b1001  # (1 * 8) + (0 * 4) + (0 * 2) + (1 * 1)
9
```

Or, to rotate it:

```
              3      2      1      0      | Entry
              True   False  False  True   | Value
0      b      1      0      0      1      | Bit    # -> 0b1001
```

---

In terms of extracting the output, the [right-shift binary operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations) `x >> y` moves all bits in `x` right by `y` places, truncating the last `y` bits:

```
>>> for x in range(4):
        print(x, '0b{:04b}'.format(9>>x))


0 0b1001
1 0b0100
2 0b0010
3 0b0001
```

and the [bitwise AND](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) `& 1` tells you the value of the last bit. Getting the results back out:

```
>>> for x in range(4):
    print(x, 9>>x&1)


0 1
1 0
2 0
3 1
```

---

Another example:

```
Entry   Value   Bit
-----   -----   ---
  0     True     1
  1     False    0
  2     True     1
  3     False    0
                 b  # needed to indicate
                 0  # 'binary number'
```

So the *"magic number"* for this lookup table, reading **up from the bottom**, is:

```
>>> 0b0101  # (0 * 8) + (1 * 4) + (0 * 2) + (1 * 1)
5
```

Or, to rotate it:

```
              3      2      1      0      | Entry
              False  True   False  True   | Value
0      b      0      1      0      1      | Bit    # -> 0b0101
```

Comment: Ohhhh, I thought you had to brute-force it. Oh, well thanks. I'll mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: And I got the same table as you when I was doing it **randomly**!

Comment: @AnirudhBalaji what do you mean *"didn't work correctly"*? If the magic number is `8`, `magic_num>>x&1 == 1` **only** when `x == 3`.

Comment: _but_ you said you were reading it from the bottom up! I did that too, and the binary representation I got: `0b1000`

Comment: @AnirudhBalaji I don't understand why you think that makes me wrong. `0b1000 == 8`, so only the fourth item (index `3`) is selected.

Comment: OK, look, the lookup table I have which gave me 8 was `True, False, False, False`

Comment: @AnirudhBalaji and if you read **up from the bottom**, that gives you `0b0001`, which is `1`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79775/discussion-between-anirudh-balaji-and-jonrsharpe).